# "long-run" or "long run"?

Tags: idioms, modifiers, formal-language, hyphens

Which is correct? For example:

> That can have long-run benefits.

or

> That can have long run benefits.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is *long-term*. We refer to *long-term benefits* or *long-term goals*. *Long run* would make more sense like this: *I know it seems difficult now, but these changes will make things better in the long run.*

Comment: @WendiKidd long-term or long-terms or long-terms'  or long-term's ?

Comment: *Long-term* is hyphenated because it's a compound adjective. *The long run* is not; I'm pretty sure it's a noun phrase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is *long-term*. We refer to *long-term benefits* or *long-term goals*. *Long run* would make more sense like this:

> I know it seems difficult now, but these changes will make things better in the long run.

*Long-term* is hyphenated because it's a compound adjective. *The long run* is not; I'm pretty sure it's a noun phrase.

Comment: The noun phrase _long run_ can be used as a compound adjective by adding a hyphen, just like _long term._